# Laravel orderBy not returning correct results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My product model has range of products with values like 20.00 or 1000.00 however using `Product::orderBy('price_1', 'desc')->take(10)->get();` the result does not show 1000.00 first it shows somewhere closer to the 20.00. Is this because of the `.` in the value or is there a better way to get the highest price first?

Comment: What is the type of this column in your database?

Comment: varchar is the type

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of the column to `DECIMAL(6,2)` (or any other precision).

The reason the fields are sorted like that is because it's a `VARCHAR` and varchars are sorted alphabetically, not by numeric value.